# Apply select bg color on load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, load

Please look at the following link to see my code in action: 
http://codepen.io/DigitalSquid/pen/mAkuC

How can I make the bg color appear on page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on `window.load` call that function with the selectbox ids..

try this

```
window.onload=function(){
 colourFunction(document.getElementById('select1'));
 colourFunction(document.getElementById('select2'));
};
```

Comment: i wish i could call both select together - maybe a general solution which would have applied to every select on in my code. thanks for this though :)

Comment: i wish you had used jquery there... :) .... http://jsfiddle.net/VaWZ7/1/ ..here is the example...

Comment: BTW, is there anything you cannot do? LOL - just kidding, i am going now, good night and thank you soo much!

Comment: i learnt all this from stackoverflow... :) :p... anyways cheers.. happy coding...

Comment: wow - i wish i become as smart as you one day - when i used this code in IE, after making the selection there is no blur i tried adding "$(this).blur;" which didn't work. what did i do wrong? i dont like when the selection is made and there is the default blue highlight rather than the bg color...

Comment: Actually once you choose every value - then the code stops working with bg colors

Comment: oppss... i forgot to add removeClass there..so it is just adding the classname there.... check this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/VaWZ7/2/

Comment: all good - cheers - programming is so funny, miss one little thing and you are in trouble ;)

Comment: The downsides to using `onload` (as opposed to `addEventListener`) is that you can only have a single event on load; if another script had already set window.onload, you've killed that handler. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902033/element-onload-vs-element-addeventlistenerload-callbak-false

Comment: @PaulRoub yes that is there.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Call `colourFunction()` for each select at load time:

```
function initialColours() {
  colourFunction(document.getElementById('select1'));
  colourFunction(document.getElementById('select2'));
};

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', initialColours, false);
}
// older IE versions have a non-standard variant, use that
else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent('onload', initialColours);
}
```